# Picard group of a Parabolic subgroup subgroups of a simple or reductive algebraic group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group for eg. $G=GL(n,\mathbb{C}).$ Let $P$ be a Parabolic subgroup of $G.$   What is the Picard group of a Parabolic subgroup? Is it the same as that of its Levi factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field is perfect, the unipotent part $U_P$ is isomorphic to an affine space and hence ${\rm{Pic}}(U_P) = 0$. Since as variety $P \cong L \times U_P$ the claim follows.

If not, the question looks more complicated, see this [article](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02063586/document) for more details. The same article gives right away an example of a unipotent subgroup with non-trivial Picard group.

Comment: Than you for giving answer to my doubt and also for the helpful article

Comment: @PinakiSaha : you're welcome ! Actually if I'm not mistaken, if $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic zero, then as variety $P \cong T \times A$ where $T$ is a product of $\mathbb G_m$ and $A = \mathbb A^m$. Hence the Picard group of $P$ is trivial. So it seems really important to say over which field $k$ you are considering your algebraic group.

Comment: @PinakiSaha : also you can accept the answer by clicking on the little green check mark if you consider that it resolved your problem :)

Comment: if $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic zero, then as variety $P\ncong T \times A$ where $T$ is a product of $\mathbb{G}_{m}$ and $A=\mathbb{A}^{m}$ not always. This will be the situation only if $P=B$ i.e.connected solvable algebraic group. In general, as a variety $P=L\times U_{P}$ where $L$ is reductive group.

Comment: @PinakiSaha : No it works for parabolic as well. You can take $T$ the usual torus, and $A$ the product of the unipotent part with the intersection of the parabolic with the opposite Borel. (For example, for $SL_n$ you can take $T$ = diagonal matrices and $A$ = the matrices in $P$ with $1$ on the diagonal. It's an affine space )

Comment: @PinakiSaha : or said in another way, reductive group are isomorphic as algebraic *varieties* as $T \times A$ where $T$ is a torus and $A$ is an affine space.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I got your point.